# Invoke my eclipse plugin by method in a java application

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, methods, invoke

I'm working on a Project to graphically visualize Java objects at runtime with a static method like `D.raw(anyObject);`.
Now I'm trying to convert it into an eclipse plugin, so the output can be shown inside eclipse. But I don't know how to provide a static method from the plugin for usage in workspace projects. I think it would be possible to provide some .jar-library into the workspace, but I still wouldn't know how to manage the step into my plugin...

I found a solution to a similar problem here: [call a own eclipse plugin method from any java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522902/call-a-own-eclipse-plugin-method-from-any-java-application)
But with that, I couldn't commit my object as a parameter...

Thanks in advance

Cedric

Comment: Why do you need to call a method in your plugin from your workspace application?

Comment: The Idea is to have a visualization that's similar to `System.out.println()`, but only graphical. We're generating html renderings and would like to display them in realtime inside eclipse when `D.raw()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem you face is that the plugin and your class will be running in separate JVMs.

One solution is:

1. Call your inspection code (I assume it needs to use runtime-reflection) from the code you want to inspect (i.e. call your `D.raw` function)
2. Serialize the inspection data into a log file
3. Have your plugin monitor the file and deserialize it when it changes and refresh the visualization

This is similar to how lots of Eclipse plugin adapters work.

Of couse, the 'real' way to do this would be to not have to call `D.raw`, but directly talk to the JVM over a socket using the same API that a tool like jvisiualvm does.

Comment: Do you have any more insights regarding the socket approach? Would improve the answer even more :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper plugin that export all the packages inside your jar. (New Plug-in Project from existing jar).

To do it create a new plug-in, edit the MANIFEST.MF -> runtime -> export packages. The MANIFEST.MF should looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Myplugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.mycompany.myplugin
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.mycompany.myplugin.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: MYCOMPANY
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: com.mycompany.myplugin.mypackage1,
 com.mycompany.myplugin.mypackage2,
 com.mycompany.myplugin.mypackagexxx
```

Then to use-it in another plug-in you have add your wrapper plug-in to your dependencies.

Comment: Hmm, so I would wrap the user application and access it inside my plugin, right? But I think i need exactly the other direction i think, or have I misunderstood something?