# Execute eclipse plugin through java code

Tags: java, eclipse

I've created a plugin in Eclipse, and I can run that plugin by selecting the option in the menu.

How can I execute this plugin through Java code? For example, before doing some operation I want to first call that plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate?

Here's where I would reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522902/call-a-own-eclipse-plugin-method-from-any-java-application

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
Platform.getBundle("id_of_plugin").start();
```

Where `id_of_plugin` is your plugin's id.  Here is the [Platform API](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Platform.html) for Eclipse Juno release.

Comment: Thanq..the plugin contains "searchInLocal" command how to execute this command? is there any function in platform ?